# makefile not expanding dynamic prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to have a makefile that will take some strings as prefixes for some files (`NAMES`) and from there work on the target and prerequisite file names. In the example below, for example, the idea would be to convert 2 a csv files (`foo.csv` and `bar.csv`) to tabular (although I'm just echoing the target and prerequisite).

```
NAMES = foo bar

PR = $(patsubst %,%.csv,$(NAMES))
TB = $(patsubst %,%.tsv,$(NAMES))

all: $(TB)

%.tsv: $(PR)
    @echo $< $@
```

This prints:

```
foo.csv foo.tsv
foo.csv bar.tsv
```

So, it looks like that makefile is not expanding correctly the prerequisites in `PR` as I would expect to see `bar.csv bar.tsv` on the second line.

However, if I print `$PR` and `$TB`, both seem to be set properly:

```
$(info $$PR is [${PR}])
$(info $$TB is [${TB}])
# prints
$PR is [foo.csv bar.csv]
$TB is [foo.tsv bar.tsv]
```

Any idea how to get this working properly?

Note that I have both `foo.csv` and `bar.csv` files in the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you're using the built in variable `$<`.  If you expand the variables manually and rewrite the makefile it becomes...

```
NAMES = foo bar

PR = $(patsubst %,%.csv,$(NAMES))
TB = $(patsubst %,%.tsv,$(NAMES))

all: foo.tsv bar.tsv

%.tsv: foo.csv bar.csv
    @echo $< $@
```

But `$<` refers to [the first prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) which is always `foo.csv` regardless of the target.

One solution might be to use a [scoped static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage).  So something like...

```
NAMES = foo bar

PR = $(patsubst %,%.csv,$(NAMES))
TB = $(patsubst %,%.tsv,$(NAMES))

all: $(TB)

# Tell make how to build a .tsv from a .csv but constrain the rule
# so that it only applies to .tsv files that are part of $(TB).
#
$(TB): %.tsv: %.csv
    @echo 'building target [$@] with $$< = [$<]'
```

The above results in...

```
building target [foo.tsv] with $< = [foo.csv]
building target [bar.tsv] with $< = [bar.csv]
```